# merging images with drag & drop - asp.NET

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, drag-and-drop, gdi

I want to build a page that user can drag & drop images over eachother, and then merge them to one image.

Somthig like this http://tympanus.net/Tutorials/ImageVampUp/ but with c#/asp.net for the server side.

Does anyone have an idea where can I start?

Comment: **http://www.1stwebdesigner.com/freebies/drag-drop-jquery-plugins/**

Comment: @huMptyduMpty Useful info for jump starting the front end work. I don't think that's what being asked for, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The C# back end really ought to be fairly straightforward.  The System.Drawing classes support alpha very well.  If you load an image that supports alpha, such as PNG, into the Image class, then when you call Graphics.DrawImage method, the transparency will be preserved, showing the underlying image behind the one you just drew on top of it.  You can control alpha in other ways, such as adding transparency to images via ImageAttributes.  That's about the best answer I can offer without more specific questions.

For the front end, javascript for dynamic html like the example you link to is probably a great way to go, especially if you use a good js framework that takes care of the browser compatibility for you.

Edit: I should mention that System.Drawing is documented to not be for ASP.NET.  The fact of the matter is though, that is the namespace where all drawing related API's in .NET are located, and drawing is a very valid use case for a web service.  You can look up Windows Imaging Components, which is their recommended alternative if you wish, but you'd be leaving the realm of C# behind.  When you aren't trying to be a super high-throughput service, I haven't seen any problems with using simple Image related calls in an ASP.NET app.